# Are there any alternatives for SSAS in .net project

Tags: ssas, mdx, dax, ssas-tabular

So I am willing to create my own BI solution in .NET project. Let's say I will have 1 million of records in Azure database. Then I have to filter the data in real time and return it to the user interface like graphics let's say. As far as I know I can use tabular model, so I would keep my data with additional aggregate columns in-memory(until now for me it's all understandable). But let's say I need to filter the data in tabular model by 3-4 dynamic filters on the user side. So I have to create mdx queries in order to achieve it. I don't have lots of knowlegde about mdx queries and I am afraid that somewhere along the line I will stuck with mdx without having solution for more complicated queries.
Maybe someone knows alternatives for tabular model? Or should I stay with tabular models and mdx(or dax)? All I am concerned about is how to filter the aggregate data in tabular model by sending queries to ssas and immediately getting result of filtered data.

Comment: By the sounds of it you just need to learn more MDX. On the MS platform, Tabular is the way to go. BTW I don't see much value in creating your own BI solution. If you are trying to sell it you have to beat Power BI. If you are trying to use it... just use Power BI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But let's say I need to filter the data in tabular model by 3-4
>   dynamic filters on the user side. So I have to create mdx queries in
>   order to achieve it. I don't have lots of knowlegde about mdx queries
>   and I am afraid that somewhere along the line I will stuck with mdx
>   without having solution for more complicated queries

You can achive the above in MDX and Dax, I feel MDX has a bad reputation its really not that difficult. Do some R&D and understand the basics. Else you can post questions on SO based on your senario and get helped.

> Maybe someone knows alternatives for tabular model? Or should I stay
>   with tabular models and mdx(or dax)?
>   If you want query performance stay with it.
>
> All I am concerned about is how to filter the aggregate data in
>   tabular model by sending queries to ssas and immediately getting
>   result of filtered data.
>   You first select if you want to build a multidimensional cube or a tabular one. Then you model your data, then you let the Cube aggregate it. Once this is done you query it using MDX or DAX. Filtering is prety natural in both MDX and DAX

Comment: But for the beginner is it a better option to start with tabular model or stay with multidimensional model? For instance, I just need that the queries itself would be powerful to filter data by various options like year, month, what was the payments after each user's first purchase, compare it by different months and etc.

Comment: Tabular is easier to setup.Plus if the above answers your question, kindly mark it as answer.

Comment: DAX and Tabular with Power BI are the direction to go. Don't waste your time with MDX